Check consecutive days in SQL
I have a dataset structured as follows which contains thousands of materials and millions of rows:



Material
Date
Stock
Demand
Supply
Projected Stock
Target Stock
Overstock




123456
24/06/2024
60
0
0
60
24
Yes


123456
26/06/2024
0
4
0
56
24
Yes


123456
27/06/2024
0
4
0
52
24
Yes


123456
02/07/2024
0
0
10
62
24
Yes


123456
04/07/2024
0
0
10
72
24
Yes


123456
04/07/2024
0
0
1
73
24
Yes


123456
04/07/2024
0
1
0
72
24
Yes


123456
04/07/2024
0
1
0
71
24
Yes


123456
04/07/2024
0
4
0
67
24
Yes


123456
04/07/2024
0
4
0
63
24
Yes


123456
05/07/2024
0
4
0
59
24
Yes


123456
11/07/2024
0
0
11
70
24
Yes


123456
13/07/2024
0
1
0
69
24
Yes


123456
13/07/2024
0
1
0
68
24
Yes


123456
13/07/2024
0
1
0
67
24
Yes


123456
14/07/2024
0
4
0
63
24
Yes


123456
16/07/2024
0
4
0
59
24
Yes


123456
18/07/2024
0
0
11
70
24
Yes


123456
18/07/2024
0
4
0
66
24
Yes


123456
19/07/2024
0
1
0
65
24
Yes


123456
19/07/2024
0
1
0
64
24
Yes


123456
21/07/2024
0
4
0
60
24
Yes


123456
21/07/2024
0
1
0
59
24
Yes


123456
21/07/2024
0
1
0
58
24
Yes


123456
21/07/2024
0
1
0
57
24
Yes


123456
25/07/2024
0
0
9
66
24
Yes


123456
25/07/2024
0
4
0
62
24
Yes


123456
30/07/2024
0
0
9
71
24
Yes


123456
30/07/2024
0
0
9
80
24
Yes


123456
30/07/2024
0
0
9
89
24
Yes


123456
30/07/2024
0
0
9
98
24
Yes


123456
30/07/2024
0
0
9
107
24
Yes


….
….
….
….
….
….
….
….


123457
24/06/2024
30
0
0
30
24
No


123457
26/06/2024
0
4
0
26
24
No


123457
27/06/2024
0
4
0
22
24
No


123457
02/07/2024
0
0
10
32
24
No


123457
04/07/2024
0
0
10
42
24
No


123457
04/07/2024
0
0
1
43
24
No


123457
04/07/2024
0
1
0
42
24
No


123457
04/07/2024
0
1
0
41
24
No


123457
04/07/2024
0
4
0
37
24
No


123457
04/07/2024
0
4
0
33
24
No


123457
05/07/2024
0
4
0
29
24
No


123457
11/07/2024
0
0
11
40
24
No


123457
13/07/2024
0
1
0
39
24
No


123457
13/07/2024
0
1
0
38
24
No


123457
13/07/2024
0
1
0
37
24
No


123457
14/07/2024
0
4
0
33
24
No


123457
16/07/2024
0
4
0
29
24
No


123457
18/07/2024
0
0
11
40
24
No


123457
18/07/2024
0
4
0
36
24
No


123457
19/07/2024
0
1
0
35
24
No


123457
19/07/2024
0
1
0
34
24
No


123457
21/07/2024
0
4
0
30
24
No


123457
21/07/2024
0
1
0
29
24
No


123457
21/07/2024
0
1
0
28
24
No


123457
21/07/2024
0
1
0
27
24
No


123457
25/07/2024
0
0
9
36
24
No


123457
25/07/2024
0
4
0
32
24
No


123457
30/07/2024
0
0
9
41
24
No


123457
30/07/2024
0
0
9
50
24
?


123457
30/07/2024
0
0
9
59
24
?


123457
30/07/2024
0
0
9
68
24
?


123457
30/07/2024
0
0
9
77
24
?


….
….
….
….
….
….
….
….



Because the date column skips and repeats some dates, it is difficult for me to do what I want.
I need to calculate whether the projected stock is 200% or more for every 28 consecutive days. So in the example above, the projected stock is 200% above the target stock (24*200%=48), so there needs to be a column which checks the current row, and looks in the next 28 days (so not 28 rows) and if every day of those 28 days the projected stock is above 48, then the relevant material is flagged. For reference, my query currently uses CTE to convert the raw data into below dataset.
 Projected_stock as (
    select 
      Material,
      Date,
      Stock,
      Target_Stock,
      Demand,
      Supply,
      sum(Stock - Demand + Supply) over (partition by material order by date,  rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Projected_Stock
    from datasource
    group by all
    order by material,date)

Thank you.
Edit:
I am using databricks and what I expect to see is that for this material 123456, next to the column Target_Stock, there is a another column Overstock, which has a flag on all rows, because therea are more than 28 consecutive days where the projected stock is above 200% of the target stock (48)

Please tag your DBMS, and the output you are expecting

Which rows should have the Overstock flag?   Can you include an id or row_number column that uniquely identifies each row?

I added the column and another material. The unique ID is the Material, and basically all rows should have Overstock flag if there are 28 consecutive days of overstock in any period which is present in the dataset.

Why do you have Overstock=NO for material 123457 and date 30/07/2024 ?  Only 1 of the 4 records with that date are below 48.

You are right, should be ? because we don't know whether in the next 28 days it will remain below or above

"Introduce the problem before you post any code" (see: How to ask)  Currently you have a useless statement ("contains thousands ..... and millions of rows"), and too much data, before finally trying to ask the question.

When you really want to post soo much data, you better post a DBFIDDLE with that data....

Postgres and MySQL versions of the solution. DateAdd function may vary for you.
PostGres fiddle
    WITH  Projected_stock as 
    (
        select 
          Material,
          Date,
          Stock,
          Target_Stock,
          Demand,
          Supply,
          sum(Stock - Demand + Supply) over (partition by material order by date,  rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Projected_Stock
        from datasource
        group by all
        order by material,date),
    CTE  as
        (
            SELECT material, c.date, 
            CASE 
               WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN projected_stock>48 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)!=MAX(CASE WHEN projected_stock>48 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) THEN '?' 
               ELSE MIN(CASE WHEN projected_stock>48 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) 
            END as Overstock
            FROM Projected_stock c
            WHERE c.date between  c.date AND  c.date + INTERVAL '28 day' --dateadd(DAY, 28, c.date)
            GROUP BY material, date
        ),
        SELECT p.*, c.overstock
        FROM CTE c
        LEFT JOIN Projected_stock p ON p.date=c.date and c.material=p.material

MySQL fiddle
    WITH  Projected_stock as 
    (
        select 
          Material,
          Date,
          Stock,
          Target_Stock,
          Demand,
          Supply,
          sum(Stock - Demand + Supply) over (partition by material order by date,  rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Projected_Stock
        from datasource
        group by all
        order by material,date), CTE  as
        (
            SELECT material, c.Date, 
            CASE 
               WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN Projected>48 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)!=MAX(CASE WHEN Projected>48 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) THEN '?' 
               ELSE MIN(CASE WHEN Projected>48 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) 
            END as Overstock
            FROM Projected_stock c
            WHERE c.Date between  c.Date AND  DATE_ADD(c.Date, INTERVAL 28 DAY) 
            GROUP BY c.material, c.Date
        ),
        SELECT p.*, c.overstock
        FROM CTE c
        LEFT JOIN Projected_stock p ON p.Date=c.Date and c.material=p.material


"Links to external resources are encouraged" (see: How do I write a good answer?).  Currently only some SQL statement is shown, and the reader must find out why this is supposed to work (or not).  (BTW: I am not the downvoter (this time ))

Queries updated to include Projected_Stock from datasource

Thanks Bart, for me this works and is exactly what I needed. The original version did the job, not sure why you needed to improve it?

Which dateadd did you use?

First I used  + INTERVAL '28 day' and it worked. Now I tried DATE_ADD(c.Date, INTERVAL 28 DAY)  but this gives an error DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE

I think you probably need something like this. Date arithmetic is Oracle.
WITH refdate  as
(
    SELECT material, date, max(target_stock) target
    FROM Projected_stock c
    GROUP BY material, date
)
select material,date
       ,case when times_over > 0 and times_under = 0 then 'Overstocked'
             when times_over = 0 then 'Not overstocked'
             when times_over > 0 and times_under > 0 then 'Sometimes overstocked'  
from                
  (SELECT r.material,r.date
         ,count(case when p.projected_stock > 2 * target then 1 end) times_over
         ,count(case when p.projected_stock < 2 * target then 1 end) times_under
  FROM refdate r
  JOIN Projected_stock p ON p.material=c.material and p.date between r.date+1 and r.date + 28
  group by r.material,r.date
  )

Unfortunately, with missing dates and possibly more than one entry per date, I don't think you can use an analytic function, so you are forced to joint your projected stock table to itself.
